# Handle processed job when sending mail

Tags: php, laravel, queue

I am using queue to send mail like this

```
public function handle()
{

    // job logic...

    Mail::to($email)->queue(new TasksFinished($msg));
}
```

How can I handle the jobs which were processed , because I need more detailed information to store to log_mail (a table in my DB) but I am getting stuck.

I need get the to/cc email, title and body of mail.

I am really respect to any ideas. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

To store to log_mail, create a new log_mail table and model class MailLog.

```
public function logMail()
{
    $mailLog = new MailLog();
    $mailLog->email = $this->email;
    // $mailLog->cc = $this->cc;
    // $mailLog->title = $this->title;
    // $mailLog->body = $this->body;
    $mailLog->save();
}

public function handle()
{
    $this->email = $email;

    // job logic...

    Mail::to($email)->queue(new TasksFinished($msg));

    // log the email
    $this->logMail();
}
```

In your `handle()` method, call the `logMail()` method after you have sent the email.

Comment: But I want to store logMail after job processed successfully, store logMail after queue maybe get fail job as well